# Filter request pipe Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, httprequest

I'm new to Node.js and I'm practicing using Filestreams and Requests. I wrote a program that gets the HTML of a reddit forum and filters it to get the title of all the posts. My code looks like this:

```
var request = require('request');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

var server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(req, response){
    var matches = [];
    var desination = fs.createWriteStream("posts.txt");
    request('https://www.reddit.com/r/TagPro/top/?sort=top&t=all', function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var re = /tabindex="1" >(.+?)</g;
            var match;
            while (match = re.exec(body)) {
                matches[matches.length] = match[1];
            }
        }
    }).pipe(response);

});

server.listen(8080)
```

Basically the array `matches` holds the filtered information, and I'm trying to pipe the contents of it to the response of the server request.

Right now my code pipes the whole html to the response, but I was wondering if I can just pipe the contents of my array so only the useful information is written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're actually handling the response twice: by using a callback (in which you extract the matches) *and* by piping it to the HTTP response (unaltered).

Instead, you should pick one or the other. The easiest way would be to not pipe the data at all, and just send back a (JSON) response once you have accumulated all the matches:

```
server.on('request', function(req, res) {
  var matches = [];
  request('https://www.reddit.com/r/TagPro/top/?sort=top&t=all', function (error, response, body) {
    // Handle errors properly.
    if (error || response.statusCode !== 200) {
      return res.writeHead(error ? 500 : response.statusCode);
    }

    // Accumulate the matches.
    var re = /tabindex="1" >(.+?)</g;
    var match;
    while (match = re.exec(body)) {
      matches[matches.length] = match[1];
    }

    // Send back the array as JSON.
    res.setHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
    res.end(JSON.stringify(matches));
  });
});
```

(notice that I renamed the response object to `res` to prevent it getting clobbered by the `response` argument of the `request` callback)

Comment: Thanks for the awesome explanation! Learning this kind of stuff can be really confusing and having someone like you explain to me so nicely is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of piping the response, you can can either call `response.write()` with each match, and `response.end` when you are finished (subject to each match concatenating properly with the previous so that the total response has all the right separators - I am not sure what is in each match), or you can send the entire set of matches in one `response.end()` call.  Which you do depends a little on how many matches you expect.